# Installing OpenSSL on Ubuntu for Rails development?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, openssl, rvm, ubuntu-10.10

I am running the latest RVM on Ubuntu 10.10 and I managed to get most of the development environment running, except for OpenSSL.

When I try to install the package I get the following error:

```
$ rvm package install openssl > error
ERROR: Error running 'tar zxf /home/ruby/.rvm/archives/openssl-0.9.8n.tar.gz -C    
/home/ruby/.rvm/src', please read /home/ruby/.rvm/log/openssl/extract.log
ERROR: Error running './config  -I/home/ruby/.rvm/usr/include -L/home/ruby/.rvm
/usr/lib     
--prefix=/home/ruby/.rvm/usr zlib no-asm no-krb5 shared  ', please read /home/ruby
/.rvm/log/openssl/configure.log
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make ', please read /home/ruby/.rvm/log/openssl/make.log
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make install', please read /home/ruby/.rvm/log/openssl   
/make.install.log
```

It seems that the original downloaded file is corrupt when I get it via RVM. So, I downloaded and unpacked it to `~/.rvm/src/openssl0.9.8` and the first error is gone (error running `tar zxf`), but I still get the other ones.

Edit: my Ruby version, if anyone cares, is:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: I followed "[Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you)" to the letter and now my system is working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you run `rvm requirements` after installing RVM? It shows a list of all needed dependencies, and supplies the recommended "apt-get" command.

```
  /usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev
```

This will install openssl and libssl-dev, both of which are required. I've installed RVM and Ruby many times on Ubuntu and always used RVM's recommended way without a problem.

Comment: It's now `rvm requirements`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have libssl installed in Ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8
```

Also install the development package:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Yes, my first instinct was to install libssl on Ubuntu, but that did not help me. The output I am showing was post libssl installation.

Comment: what about the dev package for libssl?